# Writing $1+3x^2+8x^4+21x^6+\cdots$ as a power series representation

Tags: power-series, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

How would I write the power series $$1+3x^2+8x^4+21x^6+\cdots$$ as a power series  representation (something neat similar to $\frac{1}{1-x}$)?

This reminds me of the power series $1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\cdots$ where the power series representation for that is $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$, but how would I add the Fibonacci numbers as coefficients into that?

Hints only!!

Comment: Can you please tell us the sequence of coefficients? It's not obvious to me.

Comment: The coefficients are every other Fibonacci number.

Comment: @flawr: Originally it was $x^2+3x^4+8x^6+21x^8+...$, but I factored out $x^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x) = 1+2x+3x^2+5x^3+8x^4+13x^5+21x^6+\cdots$.

You probably already know a closed form for $f(x)$.

Then, $f(-x) = 1-2x+3x^2-5x^3+8x^4-13x^5+21x^6-\cdots$.

Do you see how to get the series you want from $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$?

---

To get a closed form for $f(x)$ try combining the following equations in a way that leaves a finite number of terms on the right side:

$f(x) \ \ \ \ = 1+2x+3x^2+5x^3+8x^4+13x^5+21x^6+\cdots$

$xf(x) \ \ = \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1x+2x^2+3x^3+5x^4+ \ \ 8x^5+13x^6+\cdots$

$x^2f(x) = \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1x^2+2x^3+3x^4+ \ \ 5x^5+ \ \ 8x^6+\cdots$

Comment: $f(x)+f(-x)$ and factoring out 2 will yield the desired result. However, I don't know the closed form for f(x)...can you give me a hint on how to find that? EDIT: The coefficients remind me of the Fibonacci numbers a bit.

Comment: maybe multiply the second equation by x as well ?

Comment: I can't seem to make it finite. If you add all three up, then it results in $1+3x+6x^2+10x^3+16x^4+....$...will that help at all?

Comment: You can add and/or subtract equations. Remember that the fibonacci numbers satisfy $F_{n+1}-F_{n}-F_{n-1} = 0$.

Comment: I think I got it! $f(x)-xf(x)-x^2f(x) = 1+x$ -> $f(x) (1-x-x^2) = 1+x$ -> $f(x) = \frac{1+x}{1-x-x^2}$

Comment: That's exactly what I got.

Comment: Is the answer to the original problem $\frac{1}{x^4-3x^2+1}$?

Comment: Since $f(x) = \frac{1+x}{1-x-x^2}$ and $f(-x) = \frac{1-x}{1+x-x^2}$, adding them up (and simplifying) will yield $\frac{2}{x^4-3x^2+1}$. Factor out 2, and we get $\frac{1}{x^4-3x^2+1}$

Comment: Nevermind, I entered it in, and it was correct. Thanks for the hints.

Comment: Can I ask you another question about power series? Chat room name is "Mathy person"

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Show that if $A(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots $, then:

$$\frac{A(x) + A(-x)}{2} = a_0 + a_2 x^2 + \cdots $$

Can you apply this to your series?

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: What is the generating function for
the Fibonacci numbers?

Hint 2: How would you get
every other term of a power series?
(Big hint: What does $f(x)\pm f(-x)$ do?)

Comment: generating function for the Fibonacci numbers is $x+x^2+2x^3+3x^4+5x^5+8x^6+....$

Comment: As a rational  function.

Comment: $\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}$

Comment: What are f(x) and f(-x)?

Comment: f(x) is the power series for the fibbies.